# Maximum Daisy Chain Length

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a bunch of value pairs (Before, After) by users in a table. In ideal scenarios these values should form an unbroken chain. e.g.

```
| UserId | Before | After |
|--------|--------|-------|
| 1      | 0      | 10    |
| 1      | 10     | 20    |
| 1      | 20     | 30    |
| 1      | 30     | 40    |
| 1      | 40     | 30    |
| 1      | 30     | 52    |
| 1      | 52     | 0     |
```

Unfortunately, these records originate in multiple different tables and are imported into my investigation table. The other values in the table do not lend themselves to ordering (e.g. CreatedDate) due to some quirks in the system saving them out of order.

I need to produce a list of users with gaps in their data. e.g.

```
| UserId | Before | After |
|--------|--------|-------|
| 1      | 0      | 10    |
| 1      | 10     | 20    |
| 1      | 20     | 30    |
// Row Deleted (30->40)
| 1      | 40     | 30    |
| 1      | 30     | 52    |
| 1      | 52     | 0     |
```

I've looked at the other Daisy Chaining questions on SO (and online in general), but they all appear to be on a given problem space, where one value in the pair is always lower than the other in a predictable fashion. In my case, there can be increases or decreases.

Is there a way to quickly calculate the longest chain that can be created? I do have a `CreatedAt` column that would provide some (very rough) relative ordering - When the date is more than about 10 seconds apart, we could consider them orderable)

Answer (score 0):

Are you not therefore simply after this to get the first row where the "chain" is broken?

```sql
SELECT UserID, Before, After
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM dbo.YourTable NE
                  WHERE NE.After = YT.Before)
  AND YT.Before != 0;
```

If you want to last row where the row where the "chain" is broken, just swap the aliases on the columns in the `WHERE` in the `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: Unfortunately not, because the values can increase or decrease through any values, there could be one (or many) instances of the before/after values. I tried using the `LAG` function (I should probably add that to my question actually) to compare the expected to actual, but the ordering screws it up.

Comment: Normally, the screwup would balance itself out, but if the last record in my order also has a difference, it tends to not balance up on the whole

Comment: So what *are* you after here. Include your expected results in your question, @ObsidianPhoenix .

Comment: Note `LAG` won't help you here if a value can decrease and increase, as you (according to your sample data) has no always ascending key/id.

Answer (score 0):

the following performs hierarchical recursion on your example data and calculates a "chain" count column called 'h_level'.

```
;with recur_cte([UserId], [Before], [After], h_level) as (
    select [UserId], [Before], [After], 0 
    from dbo.test_table
    where [Before] is null
    union all
    select tt.[UserId], tt.[Before], tt.[After], rc.h_level+1 
    from dbo.test_table tt join recur_cte rc on tt.UserId=rc.UserId 
                                                and tt.[Before]=rc.[After]
    where tt.[Before]<tt.[after])
select * from recur_cte;
```

Results:

```
UserId  Before  After   h_level
1       NULL    10      0
1       10      20      1
1       20      30      2
1       30      40      3
1       30      52      3
```

Is this helpful?  Could you further define which rows to exclude?

Answer (score 0):

If you want users that have more than one chain:

```
select t.UserID
from <T> as t left outer join <T> as t2
    on t2.UserID = t.UserID and t2.Before = t.After
where t2.UserID is null
group by t.UserID
having count(*) > 1;
```